# How to send a mail using external SMTP server in Robot Framework?

Tags: email, smtp, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RPA.Email.ImapSmtp  smtp_server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  smtp_port=25
Task Setup  Authorize  account=${ACCOUNT}  password=${PASSWORD}  smtp_server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx smtp_port=25

*** Variables ***
${ACCOUNT}  xyz@abc.com
${PASSWORD}  abc123
${RECIPIENT_ADDRESS}  abc@xyz.com
${EMAIL_TEXT}  <h4>Hello</h4>
${SMTP_SERVER}  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
${SMTP_PORT}  25


*** Test Cases ***
SendingEmail
    Send Message  sender=${ACCOUNT}
    ...  recipients=${RECIPIENT_ADDRESS}
    ...  subject=ABCD
    ...  body=${EMAIL_TEXT}
    ...  html=${TRUE}
    ...  attachments=qwerty.html
```

The following error is encountered.
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host.

Any ideas how to send mail using external smtp server?

Comment: The error is a network one, the machine you run the RF script on cannot connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 25. Check your firewall settings.

Comment: Tried executing the script after disabling the firewall. Still the same output. Any solution?

Comment: Your OS cannot reach the target host on the network; open a terminal on the same machine where you run the RF script, and type `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 25`, where you put the actual IP instead of xxx. If this doesn't work - resolve your network connectivity issue; if this works, but RF not - there's a firewall rule preventing your python binary from communicating with that host.

Comment: Judging by your new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370443/succesfully-sent-an-email-using-robot-framework-but-the-email-sent-is-not-visib you managed to connect to the server, is that so?