# Succesfully sent an Email using Robot framework, but the email sent is not visible in recipient's inbox

Tags: smtp, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RPA.Email.ImapSmtp
Task Setup  Authorize Smtp  account=${SENDER}  password=${PASSWORD}  smtp_server=${SMTP_SERVER}  smtp_port=${SMTP_PORT}

*** Variables ***
${SENDER}  abc@xyz.com
${PASSWORD}  ****
${RECEIVER}  xyz@abc.com
${EMAIL_TEXT}  Hello
${SMTP_SERVER}  ***.***.***.***
${SMTP_PORT}  **

*** Test Cases ***
SendingEmail
    Send Message  sender=${SENDER}
    ...  recipients=${RECEIVER}
    ...  subject=Sample
    ...  body=${EMAIL_TEXT}
    ...  html=${TRUE}
```

This is the code that I have used. Sender is uses an external mail server. Sender and Receiver email domains are different. I have checked the log and it shows that the email was sent. But, the email is not found in recipient's inbox.

Comment: As stated, it sounds as if you sent some mail and it was suppressed by the recipient's spam filter. SO is for programming problems. If this is a programming problem (not a spam/filtering problem), would you please elaborate what the programming problem is? Thanks.

Comment: You may also need to be more patient. Email can be delayed if servers are very busy or if you have poor sending reputation. Give it 2 to 3 days. After that it should get delivered or bounce. (Make sure you used a valid sender address to receive the bounce.)